# Animation doesn't work without handlers in the first fragment of activity

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

I used animations in a fragment that doesn't work in normal state . I should use them in handlers . I'm using fragment navigation and this the first fragment of the activity that got this problem . the other fragments work fine.

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>() {
    override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (firstTime) {

        Handler().postDelayed({
            binding.finalHomeFragment.setTransitionDuration(1)
            binding.finalHomeFragment.transitionToEnd()
            binding.view.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.buttonLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            setTransition()
        }, 0)
        firstTime = false
    } else {
        Handler().postDelayed({
            binding.finalHomeFragment.setTransitionDuration(1500)
            binding.finalHomeFragment.transitionToEnd()
        }, 0)
    }


    private fun setTransition() {
        val autoTransition = AutoTransition()
        autoTransition.duration = 500
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.container, 
autoTransition)
        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clone(binding.container)
        set.setVisibility(binding.buttonLayout.id, View.VISIBLE)
        set.setVisibility(binding.view.id, View.VISIBLE)
        set.applyTo(binding.container)
    }

}
```

I used MotionLayout and TransitionManager for animation